# How to fix "Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition_9' at line '0' and column '0'" error on PowerAutomate

Tags: power-automate

Power automate fails with the following error for multiple conditions:
"Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition_9' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'."

The conditions have a similar layout, some of these work and some don't.

The input data comes from a Microsoft Form and these conditions take the answer of specific questions where a rating (1 - 10) is required.

[image]

These keep on failing and Microsoft automatically turns the flow off, however it does seem like it is working as it should even with these errors.

Any help would be appreciated, as this has been driving me crazy for the past couple of months!

Tried not converting the value it is comparing, however, this gets imported as a string so needs to be converted to an integer so that it can be compared to another integer.

I've tried different suggested solutions from other forums but non have helped with this.